# Create a surface plot of a Farfalle noodle

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, graphing-functions, surfaces

I wanted to find an equation which would result in a given type of pasta (e.g. Farfalle) when plotted. I looked into George Legendre's book *Pasta by Design* which gives some interesting equations to plot dozens of different pasta types. However, the plots in the book are only many discrete points that together look like pasta. I would prefer a continous function that gives the right surface. I tried using the points that I obtained from one of the formulas in the book to create a response surface via a second degree taylor approximation. However, this resulted in a not-so-nice approximation which was total rubbish on the pasta boundaries (which is not surprising when using response surfaces).

Does anyone have an idea how to obtain a surface plot of a Farfalle noodle? I know that other kinds of pasta like spaghetti are easier to plot but I am interested in creating a Farfalle plot. Any hints and help would be much appreciated.

Edit: as was pointed out, the teeth of the Farfalle might be hard to design. If it makes the problem significantly easier, these could be left out.

Comment: [cross=cap][1]

portions of cross cap may  be adjusted as also the Whitney umbrella.

  [1]: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=whitney%20cap&espv=2&biw=1236&bih=563&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja8fur4eXRAhVIN48KHZkrC4wQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=cross%20cap%20surface&imgrc=RGa7Vw_b8UwApM%3A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the presence of "teeth" at the boundary of the pasta, I would suggest to forget the search for an equation and rather consider using CSG (contructive solid geometry ... In case you don't know what it is about, look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry))

**EDIT :**

Here is a try, with Maple ...

[image]

> plot3d([.2*t*(.2+s^2-(1/2)*s^4), s, .3*cos(t)],
>   s = -1 .. 1, t = -2*Pi .. 2*Pi,
>   grid = [20, 60], scaling = constrained)

Or maybe better :

[image]

> plot3d([.2*t*(.1+s^2-(1/2)*s^4), s, .2*cos(t)*exp(-3*s^2)], s = -1 .. 1, t = -2*Pi .. 2*Pi, grid = [30, 50], scaling = constrained, style = patchnogrid)

To be compared with :

[image]

Comment: Why do you think the teeth cannot be given by an equation?

Comment: I have the intuition that it would be possible only by considering some parametric surface with the parameters varying in some ugly set. If we forget the teeth, I think it's not so difficult to get a neat set of parametric equations (I mean something like $x=f(u,v)$, $y=g(u,v)$ and $z=h(u,v)$).

Comment: I guess the teeth can be dropped, if it makes the problem significantly easier.